# Change name of generated classes in axis2 1.4

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis

is this possible to change name of generated complexType binding classes in axis2 (using adb) ?

Offending xsd is:

```
      <xsd:complexType name="System">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation></xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexContent mixed="false">
          <xsd:extension base="tns:SystemBase"/>
        </xsd:complexContent>
      </xsd:complexType>
```

which causes adb to generate inner System class. This is fine except for the fact that the generated stub also uses Java's System class (currentTimeMillis) method, effectively shadowing it - causing compilation error.

I'd like to map complexType "System" to something like _System.

I tried the -em switch with mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings dbf="adb">
    <mapping>
        <qname namespace="http://service.gov/schemas/AP/2014/06/01">System</qname>
        <value>_System</value>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

but is is not working (qname's namespace attr matches with targetNamespace of related xsd schema).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using -u option to wsdl2java solves the original problem (System class, and no other won't be shadowed).